# Finding Correlation of a Bivariate Function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, covariance, correlation, bivariate-distributions

Here is a bivariate function with the variables $i,j$ is given as:
$f(i,j) = Wij(i+j),$
$0<i<1,$
$0<j<1.$
Where $W$ is just a constant. Assume that $M=\min(I,J)$ and $N = \max(I,J).$
Compute Correlation$ (M,N).$

From $f(i,j)= \int_0^1\int_0^1 W ij (i+j) dxdy = 1,$ $W = 18/5.$ so that
$$f_{AB}(i,j)= \frac{18}{5} ij (i+j) di dj, \ 0 < i, j < 1.$$
$$f (i)= \int_0^1 \frac{18}{5} i j (i+j) dj= \frac{18i}{5}\left(\frac{i}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right), \ 0 < i < 1$$
$$f (j)= \int_0^1 \frac{18}{5} i j (i+j) di= \frac{18j}{5}\left(\frac{j}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right), \ 0 < j < 1$$
$$E(I) = \int_0^1 i \frac{18i}{5}\left(\frac{i}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right) di = \frac{17}{20}= E(J)$$
$$E(I^2)= \int_0^1 i^2 \cdot \frac{18i}{5}\left(\frac{i}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right) di  = \frac{33}{50} = E(J^2)$$
I am stuck beginning here. However, the idea is to find the distribution of $M$,
$$1-F_M(m) = P(I> m)P(J> m) = \int_m^i \frac{18t}{5}\left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)  dt \int_m^j \frac{18t}{5}\left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)  dt,$$
find expectation and variance of $M$. Then by symmetry, the Var$(M)=$ Var$(N):$
$$Var(I)= E(I^2) - (E(I))^2 =Var(J),$$
so that the covariance and correlation between $M$ and $N$ can be computed using:
$$Cov(QR) = E(I)E(J) - E(M)E(N)$$
$$\frac{Cov(QR)}{\sqrt{Var(M)Var(N)}}$$
*If there is any better way of solving this problem, please let me know. Any help for computing the correlation in this question is most welcome thanks in advance!*

Comment: I have $\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 i\cdot j\cdot (i+j) \ di  \ dj=\frac{1}{3} $. So $W=3$